# Free Plug-in to show caller-functions in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Very often I see code written from others, and when browsing over a function I want to see where this function is called from. Even when I debug my own code, I'd find it a useful feature:P

In c++ this feature is default in visual studio(its called browse-something), but I haven't found any such thing for VB.NET yet, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can right-click on variables and function names and use "Find References"

Answer (score 0):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) can do it, but it's not free. It's called [Find Usages](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#Find_Usages):

[alt text http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/screenshots/40/findUsages.gif](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/screenshots/40/findUsages.gif)